# UIButton in CollectionViewCell "IndexPath doesn't work"

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, collectionview

I made a simple app add uibutton to collectionviewcell but when i give action an error occurs. Here is a screenshoot.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjy5C.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp5rW.png)

and my code of class: UIbuton {}

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class KeypadUIButton: UIButton {
    var qIndex : NSIndexPath?
}
```

and my cell class is :

```
import UIKit

class ConverterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var keypadButton: KeypadUIButton!
}
```

and error in :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = padCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! ConverterCollectionViewCell
        let index = indexPath.row
       // -> cell.keypadButton.qIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath
return cell
}
```

Where is my mistake. can you help me ?

Comment: Your `keypadButton` outlet isn't connected.

Comment: In your stroyboard did you set the button class to `KeypadUIButton` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I've got your error, it seems you missed this:

[image: Custom class name]

Type in your class name: KeypadUIButton

Also you don't need to use NSIndexPath in swift. Just use IndexPath instead. So you won't need to down cast it.

Answer (score 0):

I have try with your code its work fine , please check that you give action to your button as well as custom class name to your button[image: custom button]

```
class KeypadUIButton: UIButton {
   var qIndex : NSIndexPath?
}

class ConverterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var keypadButton: KeypadUIButton!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from 
    a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 16
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let identifier : String = "test"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! ConverterCollectionViewCell
    cell.keypadButton.qIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
    cell.keypadButton.setTitle("\(indexPath.row + 1)", for: .normal)

    return cell

}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You had taken

**qIndex as? NSIndexPath**

you can take as

**qIndex as? Indexpath**

It avoid unnecessary downcasting in cellforitem.